# Iterating over columns and comparing each row value of that column to another column's value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, multiple-columns

I am trying to iterate through a range of 3 columns (named 0 ,1, 2). in each iteration of that column I want to compare each row-wise value to another column called Flag (row-wise comparison for equality) in the same frame. I then want to return the matching field.

I want to check if the values match.

Maybe there is an easier approach to concatenate those columns into a single list then iterate through that list and see if there are any matches to that extra column? I am not very well versed in Pandas or Numpy yet.

I'm trying to think of something efficient as well as I have a large data set to perform this on.

Most of this is pretty free thought so I am just trying lots of different methods

Some attempts so far using the iterate over each column method:

```py
##Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame([['123','456','789','123'],['357','125','234','863'],['168','298','573','298'], ['123','234','573','902']])
df = df.rename(columns = {3: 'Flag'})

##Loop to find matches
i = 0

while i <= 2:
    df['Matches'] = df[i].equals(df['Flag'])
    i += 1
```

My thought process is to iterate over each column named 0 - 2, check to see if the row-wise values match between 'Flag' and the columns 0-2. Then return if they matched or not. I am not entirely sure which would be the best way to store the match result.

Maybe utilizing a different structured approach would be beneficial.

I provided a sample frame that should have some matches if I can execute this properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you want in the 'Matches' column? The column name? Just True or False?

Comment: `df.loc[:, [0, 1, 2]] == df['Flag']` tells you where the matches are.

Comment: @BenPap  True or False would probably be fine. I just want signal that there is a match for that row.

Comment: @WoodyPride what if I have 123 columns and want to slice a particular cut of them from 0-123 and check if they are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) in combination with [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) than return the row if *any* of the columns match with [`.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
m = df.iloc[:, :-1].eq(df['Flag'], axis=0).any(axis=1)

df['indicator'] = m

     0    1    2 Flag  indicator
0  123  456  789  123       True
1  357  125  234  863      False
2  168  298  573  298       True
3  123  234  573  902      False
```

The result you get back you can select by boolean indexing:

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].eq(df['Flag'], axis=0)

       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True  False
3  False  False  False
```

Then if we chain it with `any`:

```
df.iloc[:, :-1].eq(df['Flag'], axis=0).any(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Your output for ```df.iloc[:, :3].eq(df['Flag'], axis=1).any()``` is slightly incorrect. It should only be 1 column.

Comment: OP should comment about that, I read _"column 0-2"_ as first 3 column (0,1,2).

Comment: @Erfan Each column name has an integer name (0, 1, 2). These columns could realistically be scattered among a data frame in any order but I am using the integers as their names.

Comment: I updated the answer, could you tell exactly whats not correct? I added a column called `indicator` that shows if there was a match or not. @Coldchain9

Comment: @Erfan Column '1', row '2' should have a match with 298 to 298 in the 'Flag' Column.

Comment: @Erfan I'm referring to the fact that ```df.iloc[:, :3].eq(df['Flag'], axis=1).any()``` actually returns only one column due to the ```.any()```, but in your answer you have the entire df.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood @Coldchain9, updated the answer.

Comment: @Erfan What does the -1 in iloc do ?

Comment: It selects all the columns except the last one @Coldchain9

Comment: A list comprehension like `df['Matches'] = [x[3] in x[[0,1,2]] for x in df.values]` is probably simpler but what @Erfan has is much faster.